# Fixed border radius for SVG

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I'm currently working on a project where a section is divided in two : a picture and a link. The section is divided diagonally and each part has a fixed border radius like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SXDx.png

For now I've been using an svg on mobile with a gray triangle and a white border to create a fake border radius on the image. The thing is once you are on tablet/desktop, the svg scales and the "border radius" becomes a border radius 50px instead of 6px.. Is there a solution I could use to fix the radius no matter the width/height of the svg? Or any other solution without using an svg with the same result?

EDIT: here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/qykdd7

Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Could you share your code and what you have done so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is a demo of what I did https://codesandbox.io/s/qykdd7